# How can I set my request headers in Cypress to avoid ignoring them?

Tags: http-headers, cypress, httprequest

Could you help to solve the problem in API testing by Cypress. When I set the request headers in options section Cypress ignores them and replaces with default ones.
The example of my request:

```
 cy.request({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://orion.koto.com/api/inn',
          Headers: {'sid':'21102xiXXdvsfykg5pj'},
          body:'["3211455115"]' ,
        })
```

the request sent by Cypress:

> Method: POST URL: https://orion.koto.com/api/inn Headers: {
> "Connection": "keep-alive",   "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36",   "accept": "/",
> "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",   "content-length": 14 } Body:
> ["3211455115"]

Comment: Working on the same topic,
Trying to setup the header in cy.visit() but it didn't work
    cy.visit({
       url: 'https://www.google.fr/',
       headers: {'green':'toto'},
    })
HTTP headers request does not contains my green parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
const green_value = "TOTO"
describe('As I have set a green header',()=>{
    it('should use this header',()=>{
        cy.visit({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending',
            headers: {
            'green': green_value
            }
        })
    })
})
```

On my side, it work with visit() function. The url used will show you header sent.
Hope this code sample can help you to implement request() function.

Comment: Thank's a lot. I'll try to do it.